# How to create a directory with current date without linebreak

Tags: command-line, 22.04, date, mkdir

Moin!

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I try to create a directory with a shell script. I searched already for solutions, but all what I found creates a folder with a line break at the end.
I tried this:

```
sudo mkdir /data/Backup/Subversion/Backup_$(date +"%Y_%d_%m")
```

and also this:

```
_Dir=Backup_$(date +"%Y_%d_%m")
sudo mkdir /data/Backup/Subversion/$_Dir
```

Another way I found with printf was also not working.
When I just enter the following, I get an output with out a line break

```
printf `date "+%d.%m.%Y"`
```

But when I combined it, I just get a directory without a date (Backup_)

```
sudo mkdir /data/Backup/Subversion/Backup_$printf `date "+%d.%m.%Y"`
```

How can I remove the line break from the directory name?
Thanks for feedback!

Martin

Comment: How exactly did you determine that there is a line break at the end?

Comment: I agree with @steeldriver ... There can't be probably almost certainly a newline character at the end of the directory name from your first example ... And for the printf one you'll need a command substitution within another like `$(printf $(date "+%d.%m.%Y"))` ... But, the visual you got from running that will be lost in that syntax ... So what you see from `printf `date "+%d.%m.%Y"`` is irrelevant to what's returned from the command substitution  ... sort of.

Comment: ... I suspect what they may be seeing is actually a *carriage return* `$'\r'` - and it's because they're doing this in a script that was created or saved with Windows line endings

Comment: ... And you suspect right @steeldriver :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume (sorry) that it is a line break based on what I saw, see screenshots:

- of my script
- shell out put after command "ls -l"
  and
- the view of the Files window.

I added one screenshot of all 3 screenshots. It's my first post, I don't know how it works.
The script was written on Ubuntu, I used Notepad++ (with wine), may be this is the problem?
I just tried it with standard text editor from Ubuntu, this works. It seems I should waste the Notepad++ on linux.

[image]

Comment: Thanks steeldriver and also thanks to Raffa, I corrected the syntax of the substitution with printf and this works now also

Comment: It's fine to use notepad++, just make sure you set the line endings appropriately. See for example [EOL conversion in notepad ++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239551/eol-conversion-in-notepad#16244079)

Comment: Thanks, I changed it in notepad++